# Apache FOP XML - XLSFO for pdf generation - how to use custom fonts in form of .otf

Tags: java, pdf-generation, apache-fop

I have seen that TTFReader class convert .ttf font in xml which can be used to refer in xml to set up fonts in unix environment .same for .pmf fonts .
But if i have file custom_font.otf how to use it ? 
How to get support for custom - open fonts ? 
Can u please illuminate me ?

Comment: AFAIK not supported yet but development of this feature is under way. Check the FOP website or mailing list to stay up to date.